# Does the map of Scala Future add any overhead?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Suppose I've got a function like this:

```
import scala.concurrent._

def plus2Future(fut: Future[Int])
               (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = fut.map(_ + 2)
```

Now I am using `plus2Future` to create a new `Future`:

```
import import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val fut1 = Future { 0 }
val fut2 = plus2Future(fut1)
```

Does function `plus2` *always* run now on the same thread as `fut1` ? I guess it does not.
 Does using `map` in `plus2Future` add an overhead of thread context switching, creating a new `Runnable` etc. ?

Comment: *to avoid the overhead associated with thread context switching* Have you determined this is an overhead from benchmarking your code?

Comment: If you want it to run on the same thread, just do `Future { plus2(plus1(x)) }`. Or even just `plus2(plus1(x))` ... to avoid the "overhead" of creating the future as well :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, I did not benchmark the code. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: @Dima You are right. I need to rephrase the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does using map in plus2Future add an overhead of thread context
>   switching, creating a new Runnable etc. ?

`map`, on the default implementation of `Future` (via `DefaultPromise`) is:

```
def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = { // transform(f, identity)
  val p = Promise[S]()
  onComplete { v => p complete (v map f) }
  p.future
}
```

Where `onComplete` creates a new `CallableRunnable` and eventually invokes `dispatchOrAddCallback`:

```
/** Tries to add the callback, if already completed, it dispatches the callback to be executed.
 *  Used by `onComplete()` to add callbacks to a promise and by `link()` to transfer callbacks
 *  to the root promise when linking two promises togehter.
 */
@tailrec
private def dispatchOrAddCallback(runnable: CallbackRunnable[T]): Unit = {
  getState match {
    case r: Try[_]          => runnable.executeWithValue(r.asInstanceOf[Try[T]])
    case _: DefaultPromise[_] => compressedRoot().dispatchOrAddCallback(runnable)
    case listeners: List[_] => if (updateState(listeners, runnable :: listeners)) () else dispatchOrAddCallback(runnable)
  }
}
```

Which dispatches the call to the underlying execution context. This means that it is up to the implementing `ExecutionContext` to decide how and where the future is ran, so one cannot give a deterministic answer of "It runs here or there". We can see that there is both an allocation of a `Promise` and a callback object.

In general, I wouldn't worry about this, unless I've benchmarked the code and found this to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it's interesting to check how it works for the default `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: I agree it hardly creates a bottleneck. Just want to understand how it works.

Comment: @Michael Like this: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L20 (Scala 2.12.x)

Comment: Yeah ... Looks like `map` creates and submits a new `Runnable` , which will probably run on another thread. That's the reason `map` requires `ExecutionContext` as its implicit argument.

Comment: @Michael You can look at other implementations of async computations, i.e. Monix Task, which is lazy and only requires a form of an execution context at the call site.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it will be suboptimal in some cases. For example, I have got a `Future` to fetch a JSON over the network and function `parseDecode` to parse and decode it. When I map the future with `parseDecode` I would probably prefer to run the `parseDecode` on another thread pool  dedicated to CPU-bound tasks. That's why I need to specify  `ExecutionContext` for each `map`. It will be interesting to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot (deterministically) use the same thread (unless the EC only has one thread) since an unbounded amount of time can elapse between the two lines of code.